# How to replace two characters after a certain character in a string according to decoding array?

Tags: php, ascii

I'm decoding mails with IMAP in PHP and I can't decode Outlook mails.

Outlook mails are using ASCII to encode characters like "čšě", but instead of "&3D" they use "=3D".

For example I need to decode "=3D=3D=3D=E8=E8=E8=3D=3D=3D" to 
"===ččč===".

Is there a way to decode those messages?

Comment: @Progman That doesn't work for characters like č.

Comment: It does, but your charset might be different. Please [edit] your question to include the full email (including the headers), the code you have where you try to convert the message, the result you actually getting and the result you want instead. Please check [mcve] to provide all the necessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use like this function. pass your string in parameter which you want to send through mail and then change these character, which you want to replace..

```
  <?php 
   function clerString($stringaIn){
        $stringaOut = str_replace('à', '&agrave', $stringaIn);
        $stringaOut = str_replace('è', '&egrave', $stringaOut);
        $stringaOut = str_replace('é', '&eacute', $stringaOut);
        $stringaOut = str_replace('ì', '&igrave', $stringaOut);
        $stringaOut = str_replace('ò', '&ograve', $stringaOut);
        $stringaOut = str_replace('ù', '&ugrave', $stringaOut);

        return $stringaOut;
    }
   ?>
```

Other method is that you should use meta tag with this code in your mail body

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```